# React-navigation: access current route stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, stack, react-navigation

Since `componentWillUnmount` is not fired while navigating between routes, this means that the more I navigate between screens, the more components are being mounted (even if I've been through these components in the stack earlier). After a while, the app becomes **really** slow because two many components are mounted at the same time (or at least that's how I understand it).

I would expect to be able to manipulate the stack in order to, for example, remove the first route when a determined number of routes are stacked, so there would be a "max number" of components mounted at the same time.
Is there any way of accessing the complete current stack (not only the current route via `navigation.state`) ? Or even logging it ? If so, how can I remove routes at a certain index ?
Right now i'm resetting the stack via `NavigationActions.reset` on a particular screen, which is not op at all.